# Is there a definition for a *geometric entropy*?

Tags: general-relativity, entropy, curvature, topology, geometry

In *statistical mechanics*, **entropy** of a system is usually defined as a measure of the system's micro-state randomness, or as an averaged "surprise" of its micro-state:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
S_{\text{stat}} = - k \sum_n p_n \, \ln{p_n},
\end{equation}
where $p_n$ is the probability of state $n$, such that $\sum_n p_n = 1$, and $k$ is an arbitrary positive constant.

In *classical general relativity*, there is no definition of **spacetime entropy**, even if there is a black hole in that spacetime.

Now, imagine some curved geometry (a curvy sheet of rubber, for example). It has some local curvature on every point on it: $R^{\lambda}_{\; \kappa \mu \nu}(x)$.

As a functional of its curvature tensor, is it possible to define a "geometric entropy" $S_{\text{geo}}$ for that sheet, as a kind of **global scalar measure of the randomness of its curvature**?  In comparison, a flat space (one for which the curvature tensor is $R^{\lambda}_{\; \kappa \mu \nu} = 0$ at every point) would have $S_{\text{geo}} = 0$.

The first idea I have as an answer is the Hilbert *geometric action* ($k$ is an arbitrary constant):
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
S = k \int_{\mathcal{M}} R \, \sqrt{-g} \, d^n x.
\end{equation}
But what else?  According to (2), spacetimes with zero scalar curvature: $R = 0$, would have 0 action (interpreted as a "geometric entropy") even if the curvature isn't 0 ($R = 0$ doesn't imply $R^{\lambda}_{\; \kappa \mu \nu} = 0$).

Comment: Where is the probabilistic character entering in classical general relativity? What are the different 'microstate spacetimes' that one 'macrostate spacetime' has the options to choose from?

Comment: In the view I'm considering, there is no probability on the geometry.  I'm just asking about a way to define a kind of "geometric randomness", or "complexity" if you prefer.  More curvy and complex is the geometry, higher should be the "geometric entropy".

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the [complexity equals action conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04993).

Answer (score 2):

This paper by Clifton et al. proposes a definition of spacetime entropy based on the square root of [Bel–Robinson tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bel%E2%80%93Robinson_tensor):

- Clifton, T., Ellis, G. F., & Tavakol, R. (2013). *A gravitational entropy proposal.* Classical and Quantum Gravity, 30(12), 125009, [doi:10.1088/0264-9381/30/12/125009](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/30/12/125009), [arXiv:1303.5612](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5612).

From the paper:

> … we therefore make the following list of requirements on the gravitational entropy, $S_\text{grav}$, that we expect to guide us:
>
> - E1: It should be non-negative.
> - E2: It should vanish if and only if $C_{abcd}=0$.
> - E3: It should measure the local anisotropy of the free gravitational field.
> - E4: It should reproduce the Bekenstein–Hawking entropy of a black hole.
> - E5: It should increase monotonically, as structure forms in the universe.

That paper offers several example calculations of spacetime entropy and its evolution, most notably it reproduces Bekenstein–Hawking entropy for a Schwarzschild black hole.

A more involved example for the spacetime entropy evolution during an Oppenheimer–Snyder–Datt spherically symmetric collapse into a black hole could be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5708).

Comment: Wow !  Thanks, I'll check these papers.  I knew (felt from the guts) that something could be defined as a measure of the geometry complexity, from curvature.